# using dynamic smil file with jw player

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, smil

I'm trying to make a online stream player with JW Player 6.

If I create a smil file with all the quality version of streams and use the code below it works fine:

```
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources: [{
                file: "/player/smil.asp"
        }]
      }],
      type: 'rtmp'
    });
</script>
```

smil file:

```
<smil>
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://host/app" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="quality1" system-bitrate="720" />
      <video src="quality2" system-bitrate="360" />
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

I want to create the smil file on the fly based on user's quality selections. (ie: discard bitrates higher than 720)

I used an asp file to create smil file dynamically but it didnt work:

```
file: "/player/smil.asp"
```

> the error: ***Error loading player: No playable sources found***

of course I set header type to ***application/octet-stream*** in the asp file but didnt solve the problem.

I also tried saving same asp file with smil extension and than set the asp handler for smil files in IIS setting. it works perfectly when I call in browser, but jw player shows same error.

any recommendation?

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where the issue is happening?

Comment: For the dynamic player , what happens if you set the player's type variable to smil?

Comment: What about type=rtmp ?

Some more information (at the bottom) - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28836/media-format-support

Comment: still doesnt work.the player works without these definitions if I use smil file directly. I modified asp file like this: http://codep.in/s but still no luck.

Comment: I think application/octet-stream is wrong, it should be - application/smil, right?

Comment: I found it on a web site and worked for on player2.htm, i ll try your recommendation and let you know.

Comment: didnt make any change. I noticed something. when I load player2 page it shows nothing about smil file firebug's network tab until I click play. (autoplay is off on both players) player1 gives the error message before I click play. it could be something related with source verification in jw player. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I think that because the extension is .asp, not .smil, the player doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I believe in this case, type:rtmp, needs to be set, for something like this, to trick the player to look past the extension.

Comment: I also tried running asp files under smil extension. the content was same as running smil file but it didnt work. I dont know why player thinks the file is not valid. It must be something related with player's source code or api's code.

Comment: In you embed code, adding type:rtmp should make the player think the file can be read even though the extension is .asp, not .smil

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24860/discussion-between-dvdnhm-and-ethan-longtail)

Comment: I modified the js api code in the question, could you check it for me please? Did I add type into right place?

Comment: I think that this line:

file: "/player/smil.asp"

Needs to be:

file: "/player/smil.asp",
type: "rtmp"

I think that will do it.

Comment: YES!! I was trying to do pretty much the same thing, except with .NET. Adding type: "rtmp" finally did the trick. I banged my head on this for 2 days - may I suggest a mention of this in the documentation somehwere? So glad I found this...you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem too. I'll add this as answer. Thanks Ethan for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining type of source solves the problem.

```
sources: [{
    file: "/player/smil.asp",
    type: "rtmp"
}]
```

Thanks to Ethan for his patience.